# How do I convert a string to a valid variable name in Python?

Tags: python, validation, string, variables

I need to convert an arbitrary string to a string that is a valid variable name in Python.

Here's a very basic example:

```
s1 = 'name/with/slashes'
s2 = 'name '

def clean(s):
    s = s.replace('/', '')
    s = s.strip()

    return s

# the _ is there so I can see the end of the string
print clean(s1) + '_'
```

That is a very naive approach. I need to check if the string contains invalid variable name characters and replace them with ''

What would be a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve using this method? There may be a better way.

Comment: `print repr("a string   ")` shows the string in quotes - neater than appending `_` to it.

Comment: I'm traversing a scene graph from cinema 4d and need to re-create it in blender. To keep things easy for me to understand I want to use the actual names of the cinema4d objects as variable names for Blender Python, so I need to adjust those first

Comment: BTW, the general conversion is called "slugifying" and searching stacoverflow or the internet for "python slugify" will find many solutions.

Comment: Thanks @samwyse ! if I only new this 13 years ago :))) Never too late to learn something new though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[According to Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), an identifier is a letter or underscore, followed by an unlimited string of letters, numbers, and underscores:

```
import re

def clean(s):

   # Remove invalid characters
   s = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z_]', '', s)

   # Remove leading characters until we find a letter or underscore
   s = re.sub('^[^a-zA-Z_]+', '', s)

   return s
```

Use like this:

```
>>> clean(' 32v2 g #Gmw845h$W b53wi ')
'v2gGmw845hWb53wi'
```

Comment: +1 for recognizing that valid characters are different for the first letter vs subsequent letters as well as only allowing valid letters vs stripping invalid letters.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela has a great point.  Since all the reserved keywords are only letters, you can guarantee there won't be a conflict by adding an underscore (if you want to be real good, you can first check if the name is a keyword and only adding an underscore if that's the case).

Comment: You can use the "keyword" module to make sure the name does not conflict with any Python keywords, "keyword.iskeyword(s)"

Comment: You can replace the first substitution string with `r'\W'`.

Answer (score 73):

Well, I'd like to best Triptych's solution with ... a one-liner!

```
>>> def clean(varStr): return re.sub('\W|^(?=\d)','_', varStr)
...

>>> clean('32v2 g #Gmw845h$W b53wi ')
'_32v2_g__Gmw845h_W_b53wi_'
```

This substitution replaces any non-variable appropriate character with underscore and inserts underscore in front if the string starts with a digit. IMO, 'name/with/slashes' looks better as variable name `name_with_slashes` than as `namewithslashes`.

Comment: If you want to collapse multiple invalid chars into a single `_`, use the following: `re.sub(r'\W+|^(?=\d)','_', varStr)` (add a `+` sign after the non-word-char `\W`)

Comment: Please do not use `lambda` to define a "named" function. It brings multiple problems. `lambda` is intended for other uses. If you insist on writing the code in a single line - in this case you can do it easily: `def clean(varStr): return re.sub('\W|^(?=\d)','_', varStr)` --- Otherwise I agree that it is usually better to replace the invalid characters than to remove them.

Comment: @pabouk i suppose i meant to show it's a single expression - but ok sure, `def` it is

Comment: @grandchild no, i wouldn't want to collapse N var-name-invalid chars into 1 `_` - i wanted that to be N `_`, as a clue how many were "erased"

Comment: @NasBanov oh, sure, the "you" in my answer wasn't meant to mean you specifically, but rather "anyone". I wanted this when I found this and I used your solution with my change and wanted to share it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built in func:`str.isidentifier()` in combination with `filter()`.
This requires no imports such as `re` and works by iterating over each character and returning it if its an identifier. Then you just do a `''.join` to convert the array to a string again.

```
s1 = 'name/with/slashes'
s2 = 'name '

def clean(s):
    s = ''.join(filter(str.isidentifier, s))
    return s

print f'{clean(s1)}_' #the _ is there so I can see the end of the string
```

EDIT:

If, like Hans Bouwmeester in the replies, want numeric values to be included as well, you can create a lambda which uses both the isIdentifier and the isdecimal functions to check the characters. Obviously this can be expanded as far as you want to take it. Code:

```
s1 = 'name/with/slashes'
s2 = 'name i2, i3    '
s3 = 'epng2 0-2g [ q4o 2-=2 t1  l32!@#$%*(vqv[r 0-34 2]] '

def clean(s):
    s = ''.join(filter( 
        lambda c: str.isidentifier(c) or str.isdecimal(c), s))
    return s
#the _ is there so I can see the end of the string
print(f'{ clean(s1) }_')
print(f'{ clean(s2) }_')
print(f'{ clean(s3) }_')
```

Gives :

```
namewithslashes_
namei2i3_
epng202gq4o22t1l32vqvr0342_
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `''.join(filter(str.isidentifier, 'i1'))` yields `i` where `i1` itself is a valid identifier. Losing the '1' unacceptable if `i2`, `i3`, ... are present in the set also.

Comment: @HansBouwmeester That depends on if one actually wants numbers in the name, I personally avoid it at all costs because there are few cases where numbers actually make it clearer (one good example of using numbers in method names is Mathf.Clamp01) usually its because someone is lazily enumerating functions which should actually get better names. With that said, I added in a line of code which also allows numbers in my answer if someone truly wants to do so.

Comment: Fair enough but the question was to convert an _arbitrary_ string to a valid variable name (i.e. identifier). Some applications will have no or little control over the incoming string contents. (I've +1 'ed the response anyway as I was not aware of the `str.isidentifier` method in Python).

Comment: In general, I think it's best if the implementation leaves _any_ string that's already a valid identifier to begin with untouched.

Comment: @HansBouwmeester To quote you, "Fair enough". If this is the case, then an additional check using >>> from keyword import iskeyword
Would be good to have to ensure the variable name does not clash with python keywords, if it does after the fixing you could add an underscore or something.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. It's what @flashk suggested back in 2010. I do like the `isidentifier` method. But applying it in the implementation could be more robust imho.

Answer (score 3):

You should build a regex that's a whitelist of permissible characters and replace everything that is not in that character class.

Comment: Or better yet, build a whitelist of permissible _strings_ and link them to actual pre-defined objects. Every time questions like this come up, I get nervous and think someone is almost certainly about to write a massive security hole.

Comment: :) not me...I'm just parsing a scene graph from cinema 4d and need to re create it in blender. Animators usually don't worry or need to worry about spaces/slashes/etc in object names