# Convert string to valid Java variable name

Tags: java, regex, code-generation

For a code generation tool I'm working on, I need to take a string and generate a valid java variable name from it, but I'm not sure about the best way to do it.

For example:

`"123 this is some message !"` => `_123_this_is_some_message` ( or something similar)

Thanks

Comment: What are the possible contents of the input string? Just alphanumerics, punctuation and spaces? Everything in Unicode?

Comment: Without imposing rules on the input, I think you'll find collisions (i.e. many-to-one mappings). Depending on your application, this may or may not matter.

Comment: You might try looping through the String and appending to a StringBuilder if it's a valid character for a Java variable name.  The challenge you might have is duplicate variables, so you might want to keep track of what you have used and append numbers if necessary.

Comment: Because the input string could be anything i was thinking about using some regex that excludes invalid characters, and some counter to keep in mind repetitions, something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303312/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-valid-variable-name-in-python , but maybe someone has better ideas.

Comment: @HugoZapata [`isJavaIdentifierPart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart(char)) and friends should help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you replace all invalid characters by `_` something like the code below could work (rough example). You might want to add some logic for name collisions etc. It is based [on the JLS #3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>   [...]
>   A "Java letter" is a character for which the method Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int) returns true.
>   A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int) returns true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "123 sdkjh s;sdlkjh d";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(s.charAt(0))) {
        sb.append("_");
    }
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c)) {
            sb.append("_");
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: Might as well append `'_'` instead (char instead of a string `"_"`).

Answer (score 4):

You want to convert random strings into valid Java identifiers. According to [the Java Language Specification, §3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.8), the definition of an identifier is as follows:

> *Identifier*:
>           *IdentifierChars* but not a *Keyword* or *BooleanLiteral* or *NullLiteral*
>
> *IdentifierChars*:
>           *JavaLetter*
>           *IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit*
>
> *JavaLetter*:
>           any Unicode character that is a Java letter
>
> *JavaLetterOrDigit*:
>           any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit

All you have to do, then, is step through your input and replace any invalid character with a valid one (e.g. underscore) or remove it altogether. Java even provides methods in the `Character` class that tells you if a given character is a *JavaLetter* or a *JavaLetterOrDigit*: `isJavaIdentifierStart()` and `isJavaIdentifierPart`. (This is much easier than trying to exclude invalid characters because the set of valid chars is small and the set of invalid chars is huge.)

At the end, remember to make sure your result doesn't start with a digit a not left with a keyword or literal. If collisions are possible and undesired, you could append numbers to your results on an as-needed basis to obtain unique values.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. Replace `\\s+` with `_`
2. Remove all occurrences of `\\W+`
3. Add `_` as prefix, if `^\d` match (or even if not)

So something like

```
"_" + myString.replaceAll("\\s+", "_").replaceAll("\\W+", "")
```

Comment: This is quite restrictive: many valid characters would be excluded with your point 2.

Comment: assylias, note that Java's `\W` should be Unicode-aware and thus fit quite well the definition of a non-identifier character.